# Is there a javascript/css compressor plugin for visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, compression, obfuscation, minimize

I'm looking for a visual studio plugin with the following functionality:

On building the project or executing the tool, the plugin looks for all **`*.js`** and **`*.css`** files in your project and compresses/minimizes them into **`*.min.js`** and **`*.min.css`** files.

Executing the tool on project build would enable you to keep the references to *.min.js in your pages while changes to the *.js files would be instantly written to the *.min.js files.

Is there such thing available?
If not what's the closest thing to automize tasks like that?

Extra question:
How about auto combining files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out these two links:

[An MS build script for YUI compressor](http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/05/how-to-create-a-yui-compressor-msbuild-task/)
[YUI compressor for VS](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2009/05/YUI-Compressor-for-Visual-Studio.aspx)

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

You probably be better off doing it with [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) and coding it to run the [compression](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/08/22/How-to-use-YUI-JS-Compressor-inside-a-NAnt-build.aspx). Automated process is always better than a manual one.

Answer (score 0):

Web Essentials is best program for that, I really like it, and it has a lot of other nice features: http://vswebessentials.com/